# Join strings for series of nested lists in Python 2.7.2

Tags: python

I have a series of lists that contain an integer and a nested list with multiple strings.  The goal is to join the strings into one string.  I have accomplished this with code that works on one list.  The problem is when I try to iterate over the series of lists there is an error: "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found."  I have tried to change the integer to a string, ignore items that are integers and direct the code to the nested list without success.

Example of series:

```
    [19497, ['83', 'CLM']]
    [19498, ['80', 'COS', 'PAN', '83', 'CLM']]
    [19505, ['79', 'MXE', 'MXN', 'MXS']]
    [19507, ['83', 'CLM', 'ECU']]
    [19509, ['79', 'MXG', 'MXS', 'MXT', '80', 'BLZ', 'GUA', 'HON', 'NIC']]
```

This works for one list:

```
    >>> q = [48, ['40', 'ASS', 'EHM', 'IND', 'NEP', 'WHM', '41', 'MYA']]
    >>> q[1] = " ".join(q[1])
    >>> q
    [48, '40 ASS EHM IND NEP WHM 41 MYA']
```

This is what I tried for the iteration and get the type error.

```
    def smush(q):
        '''STILL IN PROGRESS: Trying to create single string in nested list.'''
        for line in q:
            q[1] = ' '.join(q[1])
        return q
```

I have a feeling there is a simple solution to this I have overlooked.  Suggestions?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `line[1]` instead of `q[1]` in `smush()`? Otherwise, it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do: what's the value of `q` in `smush()`, and what should be the result?

Answer (score 1):

You're really close:

```
def smush(lists):
    for line in lists:
        line[1] = ' '.join(line[1])
    return lists # optional, since this modifies the list in-place
```

If every item is a list of exactly two elements, you should use [tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) instead, like this:

```
data = [    
    (19497, ['83', 'CLM']),
    (19498, ['80', 'COS', 'PAN', '83', 'CLM']),
    (19505, ['79', 'MXE', 'MXN', 'MXS']),
    (19507, ['83', 'CLM', 'ECU']),
    (19509, ['79', 'MXG', 'MXS', 'MXT', '80', 'BLZ', 'GUA', 'HON', 'NIC']),
]

dataInStringFormat = [(n, ''.join(l)) for n,l in data]
```

Comment: if `smush(lst)` modifies `lst` in-place then it should probably return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what will just work (without any error handling):

```
lines = [
     [19497, ['83', 'CLM']],
     [19498, ['80', 'COS', 'PAN', '83', 'CLM']],
     [19505, ['79', 'MXE', 'MXN', 'MXS']],
]

def smush(lines):
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        new_line = [line[0], ' '.join(line[-1])]
        new_lines.append(new_line)
    return new_lines

print smush(lines)
# [[19497, '83 CLM'], [19498, '80 COS PAN 83 CLM'], [19505, '79 MXE MXN MXS']]
```

Answer (score 0):

A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will succinctly do what you want:

```
a = [[19497, ['83', 'CLM']],
     [19498, ['80', 'COS', 'PAN', '83', 'CLM']],
     [19505, ['79', 'MXE', 'MXN', 'MXS']],
     [19507, ['83', 'CLM', 'ECU']],
     [19509, ['79', 'MXG', 'MXS', 'MXT', '80', 'BLZ', 'GUA', 'HON', 'NIC']]]

def smush(q):
    '''Implemented as a list comprehension.'''
    return [[x[0], ' '.join(x[1])] for x in q]
```

So presuming `a` is defined as the nested list above, then when passed to `smush` it will return:

```
In [1]: smush(a)
Out[1]: 
[[19497, '83 CLM'],
 [19498, '80 COS PAN 83 CLM'],
 [19505, '79 MXE MXN MXS'],
 [19507, '83 CLM ECU'],
 [19509, '79 MXG MXS MXT 80 BLZ GUA HON NIC']]
```

As described in [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

> List comprehensions provide a more concise way to create lists in
>   situations where map() and filter() and/or nested loops would
>   currently be used.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you have a nested list of lists like so:

```
x = [[19497, ['83', 'CLM']],
[19498, ['80', 'COS', 'PAN', '83', 'CLM']],
[19505, ['79', 'MXE', 'MXN', 'MXS']],
[19507, ['83', 'CLM', 'ECU']],
[19509, ['79', 'MXG', 'MXS', 'MXT', '80', 'BLZ', 'GUA', 'HON', 'NIC']]]
```

In which case you need to iterate over it like so:

```
for li in x:
    smush(li)
    print(li)
```

Comment: Considering that the original `smush(lists)` method already iterates over the entire collection of lists, there's no necessity to iterate over them another time; you'd be messing with the individual elements instead.

Comment: Which is why I said assuming it is a nested list of lists. If you attempt to use `smush(x)` directly on the what I've posted above, you get a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found` which is exactly what OP was complaining about.